# How to add a samsung galaxy preview on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an app, however I'm having problems with previewing for my Samsung Galaxy phone. How can I add a Samsung Galaxy preview for Android studio? Also how can I fix the layout for Android studio for galaxy phones? Currently the fields in my phone are getting cut off

Comment: You have to debug using your Samsung Phone. Android Studio only supports Google phones.

Comment: Completely incorrect. You can manually add additional screen sizes by going to AVD and creating a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to AVD Manager in Tools tab
2. Click Create Virtual Device
3. Click New Hardware profile
4. Label your new device in Device Name
5. Find the Samsung screen you want to add to Android Studio here https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/overview.html or
   go find the screen size and resolution from the phone description of
   any phone of your choice
6. Edit screen size and resolution to match
   the device of your choice
7. Hit finish